# Is there a script I can use to upgrade Windows 10 to the latest version silently?

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting, upgrade, windows-update

I have been trying to get a script working that will upgrade Windows 10 to its latest version (22H2) silently, and reboot once it has finished downloading so it can install. I tried the script I included in this post, but the computer did not reboot on its own. When I checked the log file, "Will try to download Windows Update Assistant..", was the last entry that the task logged. The weird thing is, when I reboot the computer, the upgrade starts. I'm new to this and haven't been able to figure out why the computer will not finish the download and then reboot to install. Can anyone help me get this script to work?

```
#set computer to not go to sleep
powercfg.exe -x -monitor-timeout-ac 0
powercfg.exe -x -monitor-timeout-dc 0
powercfg.exe -x -disk-timeout-ac 0
powercfg.exe -x -disk-timeout-dc 0
powercfg.exe -x -standby-timeout-ac 0
powercfg.exe -x -standby-timeout-dc 0
powercfg.exe -x -hibernate-timeout-ac 0
powercfg.exe -x -hibernate-timeout-dc 0


function Write-Log { 
    [CmdletBinding()] 
    param ( 
        [Parameter(Mandatory)] 
        [string]$Message
    ) 
      
    try { 
        if (!(Test-Path -path ([System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($LogFilePath)))) {
            New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path ([System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($LogFilePath))
        }
        $DateTime = Get-Date -Format ‘yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss’ 
        Add-Content -Value "$DateTime - $Message" -Path $LogFilePath
    } 
    catch { 
        Write-Error $_.Exception.Message 
    } 
}
Function CheckIfElevated() {
    Write-Log "Info: Checking for elevated permissions..."
    if (-NOT ([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal] [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole(`
                [Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator")) {
        Write-Log "ERROR: Insufficient permissions to run this script. Open the PowerShell console as an administrator and run this script again."
        return $false
    }
    else {
        Write-Log "Info: Code is running as administrator — go on executing the script..."
        return $true
    }
}
 
# Main
 
try {
    # Declarations
    [string]$DownloadDir = 'C:\Temp\Windows_FU\packages'
    [string]$LogDir = 'C:\Temp\Windows_FU\Logs'
    [string]$LogFilePath = [string]::Format("{0}\{1}_{2}.log", $LogDir, "$(get-date -format `"yyyyMMdd_hhmmsstt`")", $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name.Replace(".ps1", ""))
    [string]$Url = 'https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=799445'
    [string]$UpdaterBinary = "$($DownloadDir)\Win10Upgrade.exe"
    [string]$UpdaterArguments = '/quietinstall /skipeula /auto upgrade /copylogs $LogDir'
    [System.Net.WebClient]$webClient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
 
    # Here the music starts playing .. 
    Write-Log -Message ([string]::Format("Info: Script init - User: {0} Machine {1}", $env:USERNAME, $env:COMPUTERNAME))
    Write-Log -Message ([string]::Format("Current Windows Version: {0}", [System.Environment]::OSVersion.ToString()))
     
    # Check if script is running as admin and elevated  
    if (!(CheckIfElevated)) {
        Write-Log -Message "ERROR: Will terminate!"
        break
    }
 
    # Check if folders exis
    if (!(Test-Path $DownloadDir)) {
        New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $DownloadDir
    }
    if (!(Test-Path $LogDir)) {
        New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $LogDir
    }
    if (Test-Path $UpdaterBinary) {
        Remove-Item -Path $UpdaterBinary -Force
    }
    # Download the Windows Update Assistant
    Write-Log -Message "Will try to download Windows Update Assistant.."
    $webClient.DownloadFile($Url, $UpdaterBinary)
 
    # If the Update Assistant exists -> create a process with argument to initialize the update process
    if (Test-Path $UpdaterBinary) {
        Start-Process -FilePath $UpdaterBinary -ArgumentList $UpdaterArguments -Wait
        Write-Log "Fired and forgotten?"
    }
    else {
        Write-Log -Message ([string]::Format("ERROR: File {0} does not exist!", $UpdaterBinary))
    }
}

catch {
    Write-Log -Message $_.Exception.Message 
    Write-Error $_.Exception.Message 
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the computer you are running the script on needs to be updated? Near the bottom of [this](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2301187-windows-10-update-assistant-command-line-switches) page somebody mentions that if you run the executable and no update is needed that the program does not close and just sits there waiting for a user to acknowledge it. I would add a line to log that it is attempting to launch the executable above your `Start-Process` line, to help debug. Also check if the program is stuck running before you reboot if it happens again.